# How to select rows from Table X who share the least relationships with Table Y?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

suppose we have the following two tables

```
TABLE: PEOPLE
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  | john |
+----+------+
| 2  | mike |
+----+------+
| 3  | derp |
+----+------+

TABLE: Images
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | person_id | image    |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 1  | 3         | img1.jpg |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 2  | 3         | img2.jpg |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 3  | 2         | img3.jpg |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

I need to a query that selects all people from `people` table and orders them ASC by the ones that have the least images in the images table

So the order of the returned rows would be

```
John
Mike
Derp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do an outer join to the images table, then count the number of non-null image IDs per user.

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.name,
       COUNT(i.id) AS image_count
FROM PEOPLE p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Images i
    ON p.id = i.person_id
GROUP BY p.id,
         p.name
ORDER BY COUNT(i.id);
```

([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/829dd1/2).)